# Flatten Multi-Dimension Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, flatten

I have a multi-dimentional Laravel collection called transactions. When output as an array, it looks like this:

**print_r(transactions->toArray())**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Level 1
            [subcategories] => Array
                (
                     [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Level 2
                            [transaction_reference] => Array
                               (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [name] => Level 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4
                                                    [name] => Level 4
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [name] => Level 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 5
                                                    [name] => Level 4
                                                )
                                        )
                               )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

At level 2, there is an array called "transaction_reference" which contains two elements - each of which contain one more element. I need these two elements to be merged so transaction_reference contains only one element which in turn contains two elements.

In other words, I need the result to resemble the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Level 1
            [subcategories] => Array
                (
                     [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Level 2
                            [transaction_reference] => Array
                               (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [name] => Level 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4
                                                    [name] => Level 4
                                                )

                                                (
                                                    [id] => 5
                                                    [name] => Level 4
                                                )

                                        )
                               )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried using `flatten()` in a variety of formats, but cannot seem to get what I require.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a quick helper that's going to do this for you. You're going to nee to walk the array and modify the original reference to create the output that you want. I do have to ask though, why do you need to change it? Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Hmm. That's what I was worried about.  Instead of that then, is there a way to achieve the same results when collecting the data?  My controller statement goes something like `$transactions = Transaction::with('subcategories.transaction_reference.children')`

Comment: You may be able to do it, but I couldn't write the query quickly and efficiently for you, sorry.

Comment: Why do you need to merge all `transaction_reference` into a single one? Looks problematic since you will only have a single `id` for example.

Comment: The multiple ‘transaction_reference’ nodes are too low level. I want to group them more generically. For example, if ‘transaction_reference’ were fruit, I would want to show a single node for ‘Apples’ instead of the multiple ‘granny_smith’ and ‘pink_lady’ nodes. Children of these should be merged. As for the reason, I will be looping over the results to write a table. I want a single row in my table. The first cell being the transaction reference and the second cell being a sum() of the children (which are actually floats). I can’t do the sum if they are split across two parents. Make sense?